# Saving gitlab job artifacts with different conditions (when)

Tags: gitlab-ci

There is a job that saves artifacts only when the job fails:

```
artifacts:
  paths:
    - '**/foo'
    - '**/bar'
  when: on_failure
```

Is it possible to configure it so that the `foo` artifact is saved only `when: on_failure`, while the `bar` artifact is always saved (`when: always`)?

I couldn't find such examples in the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactswhen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't conditionally change the paths that are put into artifacts.

One possible workaround is to use the `after_script:` to move artifacts conditionally into a directory specified in `artifacts:paths:` based on the success status of the job script ([`$CI_JOB_STATUS`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)).

So your job might look something like this:

```yaml
my_job:
  script:
    - make build
  after_script:
    - shopt -s globstar # enable glob star patterns in bash 
    - mkdir artifacts
    
    # always collect **/bar
    - mv **/bar ./artifacts

    # conditionally collect **/foo
    - if [[ "$CI_JOB_STATUS" == "success" ]]; then mv **/foo ./artifacts; fi
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifacts
    when: always
    # artifacts:paths: is always the same, but the contents are conditional
```